# Who sent the poster ninjas after Scott Pilgrim?

Tags: comics, scott-pilgrim

In the [Free Comic Book Day comic](http://scottpilgrim.wikia.com/wiki/Free_Scott_Pilgrim) of Scott Pilgrim, he's attacked by eight teenage girl ninjas who materialize out of posters.

I don't remember a reference to this in the standard comics and it doesn't seem to be established in the comic so I was wondering, **who sent them?**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**It seems likely that they were sent by Roxanne "Roxie" Richter.**

*Evidence in favour;*

- She is known to be an accomplished *poster* artist
- She is known to be "*half*-*ninja*" (the free comic states that the spell must use ninja magic)
- Ramona seems very sheepish and admits that it was very likely one of her exes, borne out by the fact that they exclusively attack Scott.
- The fight itself is extremely reminiscent of Scott's later encounter with Roxie, notably  his inability to hit girls and the fact that Ramona uses Scott as a weapon (by controlling his fists).

[image]

[image]

Note also that she neatly evades the question of whether it was an ex-**boy**friend